# Erase function wrong call

Tags: c++, arrays, string, vector

I am writing this code

```
string largestNumber(const vector<int> &A) {
        {
        //Doing something
        }
        result.append(to_string(A[maxindex]));
        A.erase(A.begin()+maxindex);
    }
    cout << result;

}
```

Now in this I am using the erase function correctly. Passing the iterator from the start and adding index value to it.So what am I doing wrong here?

The error comes

```
no matching member function for call to 'erase'
```

I have included the vector header as

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
```

Answer (score 1):

> *"Now in this I am using the erase function correctly."*

No you don't.

According the declaration described [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase)

> #### Type requirements
>
> -T must meet the requirements of MoveAssignable.

you cannot modify a `const` referenced `std::vector`, `erase()` requires a non const reference, so what's actually unclear about the compiler error message?

You have to declare your function that it receives a non const reference parameter:

```
 string largestNumber( /* const */ vector<int> &A) {
                       // ^^^^^ omit this
```

or make it eligible for moving

```
 string largestNumber( vector<int> &&A) {
```

Comment: Basically I want to remove the the integer at index = maxindex. How should I go about it?

Comment: @SagarGrover If so (and I have doubts that's the right action), you need to pass a non const reference parameter.

Comment: I wonder how hard it is to slip a "cannot call non-const method on const object" message into the compiler. Can't be trivial or someone would have done it by now.

Comment: @user4581301 It's simply impossible, **that hard**.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ You did not show how to declare function correctly and that it is better to use std::next or std::advance function insetad usinh operator + because otherwise the cond depend on the iterator type.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Better?